# Deploying Google Cloud Run to the Free Tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Google defines the [Free Tier for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#cloud-run) as

```
2 million requests per month
360,000 GB-seconds of memory, 180,000 vCPU-seconds of compute time
1 GB network egress from North America per month
```

I deployed a container with [gcloud run deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy).

```
gcloud run deploy cgps-registration-2 \
    --platform managed \
    --region us-central1 \
    --image gcr.io/cgps-registration-2/cgps-registration-2 \
    --add-cloudsql-instances cgps-registration-2:us-central1:cgps-reg-2-postgre-sql \
```

Can I change it to free tier after the fact? If not, can I pass parameters to this command that would establish this at the free tier from the start?

Answer (score 3):

There are no settings to select Free Tier. Free Tier credits are applied to the billing account at the end of each billing period. There is nothing extra to do.

Comment: I have a cloud run instance with a Postgress DB that at this point is just a testing server while I am developing. It is accessed maybe a few times a week for 10min at a time by 1-3 people. Yet, it's costing me over $100 / month. Does this sound right? Where could I look to lower some costs?

Comment: @AdamG - Your billing statement will tell you what you are paying for in detail. Where is PostgreSQL running, on Cloud SQL? That will be your bigger cost item.

Comment: Yes! It does in fact look like Cloud SQL is the hog. (https://cln.sh/OeFmLG). Is there any way to just use SQLLite with Cloud Run? This database too, though always running, should be barley under any use at all and is set down to min settings (https://cln.sh/3TvHcy)

Comment: @AdamG - Post a new question with details. However, lacking details, no you will not be able to use SQLite to replace Cloud SQL in most situations.